# Error install rpy2: 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, r, system, rpy2

I try install *rpy2* but I have this error below.

I read in the web that the problem it's the Environment Variables but I have  *C:\Rtools\bin* and *C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin* in System Variable Path.

what am I doing wrong?

Error:

```
C:\Users\rmalveslocal>pip install rpy2
Collecting rpy2

  Downloading rpy2-2.7.6.tar.gz (177kB)
    100% |################################| 180kB 1.3MB/s

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
    Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

    R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
    You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
    GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
    For more information about these matters see
    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

    'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
    C:\PROGRA~1\R\R-32~1.2\bin\x64\R CMD config --ldflags
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

      File "c:\users\rmalve~1\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-build-vvy8sl\rpy2\setup.p
y", line 291, in <module>
        ri_ext = getRinterface_ext()
      File "c:\users\rmalve~1\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-build-vvy8sl\rpy2\setup.p
y", line 198, in getRinterface_ext
        ldf = shlex.split(' '.join(rexec.cmd_config('--ldflags')))
      File "c:\users\rmalve~1\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-build-vvy8sl\rpy2\setup.p
y", line 151, in cmd_config
        universal_newlines = True)
      File "C:\Users\rmalveslocal\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 573, in chec
k_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('C:\\PROGRA~1\\R\\R-32~1.2\\bin\\x6
4\\R', 'CMD', 'config', '--ldflags')' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\rmalve~1
\appdata\local\temp\2\pip-build-vvy8sl\rpy2
```

Comment: I tried to install it for 2 days with no luck. gl

Comment: What version of python?

Comment: @Monkpit  Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)

Comment: In the rpy2 docs: `rpy2 is most likely not working with Python 2.6. Older Python like 2.5 or even 2.4 might compile, but there is much less testing done with those platforms, if any, and likely limited hope for free support.

While Python 3.3 is supported, earlier version of Python 3 are not (they might work, they might not - you are on your own).`
http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/en/version_2.7.x/overview.html#installation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882477/rpy2-install-on-windows-7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882477/rpy2-install-on-windows-7)

Comment: Are you running this from cygwin?

Comment: @PierreLafortune Although there is no real support of rpy2 on Windows Kardu got an answer about an hour after posting here. Share what did not work for you: at the very minimum it will help identify install issues occurring the most.

Comment: @PierreLafortune I followed what Konstantinos Evangelidis told, and worked in python 2.7 and 3.5

Comment: @YubinLee different error message

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Download the version you need here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2
2. Open Anaconda Prompt and navigate to the folder you have downloaded the file
3. Run pip install file_name.whl

Comment: Works :-) Thanks @Konstantinos

Comment: Worked like a charm! Would you please explain why is that the case?

Comment: These are only for Windows user, how about Linux users?

Comment: @ShichengGuo I think it's more common for  Linux users to have `sh`

Answer (score 0):

To solve:

> 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

You need to add `sh.exe` to your path. Some programs  such as GitHub Desktop (e.g., `C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\app-0.7.0\resources\app\git\usr\bin`) or Cygwin come with `sh.exe`.

I recommend http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2 + e.g. `pip install rpy2-2.8.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` as Konstantinos Evangelidis mentioned, it makes life much easier.

Your next step might be: [Rpy2 error wac-a-mole: R_USER not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24414540/395857)