# RPy2 on Windows Jupyter notebook: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, r, windows, environment-variables, rpy2

When I try and load the R extension using:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\Robert.Levy\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py in <module>()
     14     R_HOME = (os.environ["R_HOME"], )
     15 except KeyError:
---> 16     tmp = subprocess.check_output(("R", "RHOME"), universal_newlines=True)
     17     R_HOME = tmp.split(os.linesep)
     18     del(tmp)

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm running Python 2.7.1 on Windows 10 with no admin rights.

I have R installed to a local directory `username\Documents\R\...` but due to lack of admin rights, there's no entry in my `PATH` and no environment variable called `R_HOME`.

I've added an account-level environment variable with this name, but `os.environ` seems not to pick these up.

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The Jupyter Notebook you interact with (in the browser) is really just a front-end on a process which runs in a command window. Restarting the kernel is not enough to "refresh" environment variables.

The window must be closed and a new one opened.

After setting your profile-level environment variable to:

```
C:\Users\{username}\Documents\R\R-3.4.1
```

shut down the kernel, making sure the command window closes, then restart Jupyter Notebook and the new environment variables will be available.

Note that you may also need [to add an `R_USER` environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414540/rpy2-error-wac-a-mole-r-user-not-defined) with your Windows username.