# Run R script in Django

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm building a site which contains lot of optimization work and all those work are done in R language. I'm building whole site on Django. Is there any way I can connect both R code and Django or what should I do here ?

I tried installing `rpy2` which works fine in python but in `Django` I'm getting a error:

```
  File "F:\django-app\restapi\views.py", line 25, in <module>
  import rpy2.robjects as robjects
  File "F:\django-app\venv\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject
  File "F:\django-app\venv\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\robject.py", line 6, in <module>
    rpy2.rinterface.initr()
  File "F:\django-app\venv\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 208, in initr
    initr(r_preservehash=r_preservehash)
 RuntimeError: R_USER not defined.
```

what's the best option to do this. Is there any thing I'm missing here?

Comment: Does this help you? [Rpy2 error wac-a-mole: R_USER not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414540/rpy2-error-wac-a-mole-r-user-not-defined)

Comment: no, I tried it but still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing WSGI use the first Django sub interpreter?

Check this [article](https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ApplicationIssues.wiki).