# Mysterious rpy2 with Anaconda (Windows) error

Tags: python, r, rpy2

OK, after a lot of Hassle, I finally installed Rpy2 on windows 7 x64.

VERSION INFO:

R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16) -- "Full of Ingredients"
   Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
   Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

C:\Anaconda>conda -V
   conda 3.18.5
   C:\Anaconda>python
   Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Nov  7 2015, 13:18:40) [MSC v. 1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Now, it is running, but I had to do strange things
[How to setup environment variable R_user to use rpy2 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698877/how-to-setup-enviroment-variable-r-user-to-use-rpy2-in-python)

So, I have Anaconda and R installed for all users, not just for myself.  So this changes things slightly according to that post.

I had to set up environment variables

```
R_HOME C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\
R_USER C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\rpy2\
```

When running my program, I get an error in Python:

```
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in library(modeltools) : there is no package called 'modeltools'
Error in library(modeltools) : there is no package called 'modeltools'
```

So I loaded R and modeltools was not installed.  So installed modeltools and other necessary packages I found in Python source code.

I even rebooted.

And the error remains.  I am totally stumped.

Comment: I spent a day trying to install and run rpy2 with Windows and finally gave up.

Answer (score 1):

The `RRuntimeError` is an exception coming from the embedded R: it does not find the package "modeltools". Really.

So now how can this happen while when running R the package is installed ?

- `rpy2 is linking to a different R
- the paths in which R packages are installed differs

Try checking if what the R function `.libPaths()` is returning differs between R, or the R embedded in rpy2.