# How do I solve 'cannot load library error' with rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to run a function contained within an R script from Python. I've installed rpy2 but my script is failing on the first line:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
```

With this error:

```
Exception has occurred: OSError
cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e
```

I've searched and I can't find exactly the same error coming up anywhere else. However, I did try a couple of other fixes neither of which worked:

1. Adding `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3\bin\x64` to my path
2. Running `os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.3'` at the very start of my script

Comment: Have you added R_USER to your System Variables?

Comment: Yep. Followed the guidance here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25479841/11277108. Also tried adding ```R_USER``` to User variables as per the comments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.2\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63863449/oserror-cannot-load-library-c-program-files-r-r-4-0-2-bin-x64-r-dll-error-0)